# Определить жесткий диск по умолчанию

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно определить, какой жесткий диск используется по умолчанию? То есть, например, тот, на котором установлена система?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
string path = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

Взято отсюда: [How to get current windows directory e.g. C:\ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7249715/5752652)